# Binding a View to my main window only shows me the type

Tags: mvvm

I'm trying to bind a View to my ContentControl. Currently, it just shows me the type (eg NameSpace.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel)

Although I will point out, I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly.

My simple set up is I have a View (UserControl) which is empty other than a single control (which has been placed just for the visual).

My MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DelegateGoodExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DelegateGoodExample.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Height="147" Margin="53,132,60,0" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Content="{StaticResource Vm}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

(There is nothing in the code behind).

My MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace DelegateGoodExample.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView 
        { 
            get { return new View.QuickView(); } 
            set { _currentView = value; } 
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is,

1. Do I have to set a datacontext in this instance (and even if I do add it the results persist)?
2. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a *viewmodel* inside the `ContentControl`, not a view. Since your viewmodel class is not a [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) and there is no `DataTemplate` to determine how it should be rendered, what gets displayed is simply its `.ToString()` representation.

An immediate fix would be:

```
<ContentControl Height="147" Margin="53,132,60,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Vm}, Path=View}" />
```

However, instead of doing things this way you should be putting your view inside the `Grid` directly, and the viewmodel should not have any knowledge of the view.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost, you suggest I put into a grid like this but give an example of a contentControl :) Should I be putting this into a Grid?

Comment: @DaveRook: You can bind to the `View` property of the VM (I added an example). But usually things happen the other way round: the view gets directly added to the logical tree -- not to mention that in general a `ViewModel` should not know how many and what views are bound to it, which obviously is not possible if there is a `View` property in the first place.

Comment: Perfect, (again), this means I need to update my approach as I'm doing it backwards. Once again, thank you Jon

Comment: Jon, you said it should not know of the view. Please see this tutorial http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/comment-page-1/#comment-4902 ... Would you say this is the wrong approach because if it is right or wrong?

Comment: @DaveRook: Please be *way* more specific.

Comment: Sorry Jon, let me re-phrase. I assume it is OK for my MainWindowViewModel to have a property of type object which is my View and this is bound to the ContentControl Content (if not then I have no idea how to bind a view to my MainWindowViewModel)

Comment: @DaveRook: It's kind of backwards. Even when VMs have knowledge of views, it's not done so that the views can be exposed to the world. The mantra is: create view & viewmodel, view.DataContext = viewModel and then put the view somewhere it can render itself. This last step is done manually e.g. `ItemsControl.Items.Add(view)` and not by binding.

Comment: Jon, I have the feeling my question isn't clear. however, I've asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091090/changing-a-view-in-the-mvvm - Would you please give me your opinion on the answer. If you agree then it means my question wasn't clear, in which case I must apologies.