# Changing a view in the MVVM

Tags: .net, mvvm

If my MainWindow has the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="DaveMVVM.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:DaveMVVM.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:DaveMVVM.View"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
        </Grid.Resources>        
        <view:MyFirstView />        
    </Grid>   
</Window>
```

then can I assume I can't change the View from MyFirstView... For example, I will want my MainWindow to just be a frame which practically only hosts the `Menu`, and depending on what option they select from the `Menu` will depend on what View is displayed.

So, my 2 questions are

1) Am I correct in thinking that the above example will not work since the View is hard coded.
2) Do I have to use DataTemplates which are bound to my MainWindowViewModel, and then have a DataTemplate created for each View?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this as follows:

Your MainWindowViewModel exposes a property `CurrentContent`. It returns a common base type of all your view models:

```
public ViewModelBase CurrentContent
{
    get { return _currentContent; }
    private set
    {
        if(value == _currentContent)
            return;

        _currentContent = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentContent");
    }
}
```

Based on the selection of the user, you would set that property to the corresponding view model.

Your main view would contain a `ContentControl` that is bound to this property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" />
```

Finally, your view - or a separate resource dictionary - would have to contain data templates for each of the possible content view-models:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyFirstViewModel}">
    <view:MyFirstView /> 
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MySecondViewModel}">
    <view:MySecondView /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you again Daniel. This is exactly what I did have but I was concerned I was doing it wrong! D'oh. Thank you so much for your help once again.

Comment: @DaveRook: You are welcome and no, you weren't doing it wrong. It's the correct approach, giving you maximum de-coupling and flexibility.